# How to Embed and Use a <script> from an Obsidian Plugin

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, obsidian

This is my first Obsidian Plugin, and I haven't been able to figure out how all things work. What I would like my plugin to do is embed the [WGo.js SGF player](http://wgo.waltheri.net/demo/player/1). The [WGo.js package](http://wgo.waltheri.net/player) has been published on NPM but I've never been able to make it work for some reason — the docs seem outdated, you can see it in action [on my website here](https://fanaro.io/articles/tesuji_mor/tesuji_mor.html).

> [This](https://github.com/psygo/obsidian_sgf_viewer) is what I have so far for this project.

> I've also posted about this on [Obsidian Discourse](https://forum.obsidian.md/t/obsidian-sgf-viewer-go-board-game/68722).

If using the `<script>` method, I imagine the necessary steps as:

1. An SGF file is linked with custom syntax, e.g. `!![game1.sgf]`.
2. Under the hood, this is replaced by its respective WGo.js `<div>` by the plugin.
3. The plugin will use `<script>` tags to bring WGo.js into showing an embedded viewer with the game.

How do I do this through an Obsidian plugin?

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/wgo/wgo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/wgo/kifu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/wgo/sgfparser.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/wgo/player.js"></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/wgo/basicplayer.js"
></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/wgo/basicplayer.component.js"
></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/wgo/basicplayer.infobox.js"
></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/wgo/basicplayer.commentbox.js"
></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/wgo/basicplayer.control.js"
></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/wgo/player.editable.js"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../assets/wgo/scoremode.js"></script>
<script
    type="text/javascript"
    src="../../assets/wgo/player.permalink.js"
></script>
<link
    rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css"
    href="../../assets/wgo/wgo.player.css"
/>

<!-- This would be the replacement of a custom syntax, e.g. `!![AncientGame.sgf]` -->
<div
    data-wgo="AncientGame.sgf"
    data-wgo-board="stoneHandler: WGo.Board.drawHandlers.NORMAL,
                                    background: '../../assets/wgo/textures/wood2.jpg'"
    class="SGF"
>
    <p>
        Your browser doesn't support the WGo.js Player. Please use a more
        modern browser, like Brave, Chrome, Firefox or Edge.
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Incomplete answer over here, but I thought I would share the progress I've had so far.

I've managed to make WGo.js work imperatively through JS while also adding the `<div>` element to the document's body:

```js
import { SimplePlayer } from "wgo";

...

async onload() {
    await this.loadSettings();

    this.addSettingTab(new SgfViewerSettingTab(this.app, this));

    this.addCommand({
        id: "add-sgf-game-viewer",
        name: "Add SGF Game Viewer",
        editorCallback: (editor: Editor, view: MarkdownView) => {
            const div = document.createElement("div");

            const simplePlayer = new SimplePlayer(div, {
                sgf: "(;SZ[19];B[pc];W[pe]C[You have many choices - for example: R13];B[qg]C[Click on a letter to select a variation](;W[of]C[Old joseki];B[mc];W[qc];B[qb];W[qd];B[qj];W[ob];B[pb];W[oc];B[od];W[pd];B[oa];W[nd];B[nb];W[oe];B[jc])(;W[qc];B[qb];W[qd];B[mc](;W[og];B[pg];W[oh];B[pi];W[ob];B[pb];W[oc];B[pd];W[od];B[qe];W[re];B[qf];W[rb];B[oe];W[ne];B[pf];W[md]TR[rb][qc][qd][re]C[Marked stones are not dead yet.])(;W[pg];B[ph];W[ob];B[pb];W[oc];B[od];W[pd];B[nc];W[nd]MA[og]C[White can play at X as well.];B[oe];W[nf];B[oa];W[of];B[nb];W[qh];B[qf];W[pi];B[oh];W[ri];B[rh];W[qi];B[pf];W[nh];B[re];W[oc];B[ob];W[ne];B[oc];W[rg];B[rf];W[sh];B[rc]C[Interesting joseki])))",
            });

            const workspace = document.body.querySelectorAll(
                ".workspace-tab-container"
            )[1];

            workspace!.append(div);
        },
    });
}
```

I don't know yet how to properly place this in Obsidian's editor, and I doubt this is supposed to be how plugins should interact with it. And there's also the problem of customizing WGo.js a little bit more, not to mention that the SGF is hardcoded so far. But overall this is a solid direction, I think.

Comment: I think you should add this as an update section in your question, instead of posting an answer, since it's not a complete answer.

Answer (score 1):

As per [Obsidian docs](https://docs.obsidian.md/Plugins/Editor/Editor+extensions#Do+I+need+an+editor+extension%3F), you shouldn't fixate on building a plugin, lest you might need an extension instead for your use case.

### Pro Solution

If you're looking to build a full-blown plugin, which when encounters the markdown `!![game1.sgf]`, it should show the [WGo.js SGF player](http://wgo.waltheri.net/demo/player/1), in the ***reading view*** and ***live preview***, you'll have to write an extension (registered with an Obsidian plugin) to [extend CodeMirror's](https://codemirror.net/docs/guide/#extending-codemirror) capability to process the markdown. CodeMirror, under the hood uses [@codemirror/lang-markdown](https://github.com/codemirror/lang-markdown) package for this, which in-turn makes use of [@lezer/markdown](https://github.com/lezer-parser/markdown). The latter ([@lezer/markdown](https://github.com/lezer-parser/markdown)) can be extended using [it's own extensions](https://github.com/lezer-parser/markdown#extension), to add a particular processor for some markdown. For e.g., the package by default [includes](https://github.com/lezer-parser/markdown/blob/main/src/extension.ts#L8) an extension to parse GitHub flavored strike-through markdown, which is what you'll need to do for showing a ***live preview*** for an SGF player, but then a little issue that ensues is that it's not apparent, as to how to register this with the CodeMirror instance used by obsidian. For that you'll have to use unexposed Obisidian API.

### Just Get By Solution

For having the Obisdian show an SGF player in the ***reading view*** only (not live preview), you can simply [register](https://docs.obsidian.md/Reference/TypeScript+API/Plugin/registerMarkdownPostProcessor) a markdown post processor, with that you'll have to manipulate already html converted markdown for `!![game1.sgf]` to show the SGF player.

### Better Than Just Get By Solution

Instead of muddling your way to "Pro Solution", to get everything right, you can consider changing the syntax for SGF player to use a code fence block, and [register](https://docs.obsidian.md/Plugins/Editor/Markdown+post+processing#Post-process+Markdown+code+blocks) a markdown code block processor, then you'll be able to get this in reading mode and live preview. For e.g., you can use this syntax -

````
```sgf
 https://www.gamesource.com/game1.sgf
```
````

get the source of the game, load it in the element provided by obsidian. Ideally, you should allow only one link in an `sgf` code fence.

### Something to consider

Instead of loading the `wgo` through `script` tags, just bundle it with your plugin. In the `onload` callback, add it to `Window` object and remove it from `Window` object in the `onunload` callback. Obsidian itself adds many functions and objects on `Window` object.

#### **EDIT**

Per your comment, you can look for any changes in the editor like this -

```ts
this.app.workspace.on("editor-change", (editor: Editor, info: MarkdownView) => {
    // do your thing
});
```

**NOTE**: If you need to get some elaboration on a particular part or clarification, add a comment and I'll update the answer.

Comment: [API Reference](https://docs.obsidian.md/Reference/TypeScript+API/Workspace/on_10) and source code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the WGo.js player to your Obsidian plugin, first make sure to include the library in your project by importing it using a  tag. You can copy the library from the 'node_modules' folder by using the following code: `import '../node_modules/wgo/wgo.min.js';`

now create a function that will handle the replacement of your custom syntax with the  containing the WGo.js player

```
    function addWGoPlayer(){
 //variable will match your custom syntax
        const syntax = /\!\!\[(.*)\]/g;
    
        //using Obsidian's replace method to replace the syntax with the <div>
        this.app.workspace.activeLeaf.view.change(
            (view) => view.editor.replace(syntax, '<div data-wgo="$1" data-wgo-board="stoneHandler: WGo.Board.drawHandlers.NORMAL, background: \'../app/assets/wgo/textures/wood2.jpg\'" class="SGF"><p>Your browser doesn\'t support the WGo.js Player. Please
```

to call function when user opens a note, you need to add it into your plugin's onInit function:

`this.app.workspace.on("file-open", embedWGo);`

this is for replacing syntax with the , after this you need to update paths to match file structure

now when your custom syntax is added in note and it opens, WGo.js player gets embedded for use

You can go to WGo.js documentation to read more